# Process Post response in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm at a loss for how to process results from a post in play framework. The following code works to process a GET response:

```
WSRequestHolder request = WS.url(myURL);

return async(
    request.get().map(
        new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
            public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                String json = response.getBody();
                System.out.println("Json response: " + json);

                //Do stuff                          

                return ok(json);            
            }
        }
    )
);
```

I thought I'd just be able to replace `.get()` with `post(myvalue)`. However, this does not work. What is the proper way to process a POST response in Play Framework?

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"?

Answer (score 0):

`WSRequestHolder.post(...)` accepts 4 different types as a parameter: `java.io.File`, `java.io.InputStream`, `JsonNode` and `String`. You *can* replace `.get()` with `.post(myvalue)`, depending on what `myvalue` is and what `Content-Type` `myURL` is expecting.

`POST`ing with those types will set the `Content-Type` header appropriate to the type. Passing a `JsonNode` will automatically set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, for example. However, when passing a `String` you will likely have to set the `Content-Type` yourself, as Play isn't going to know whether that `String` is supposed to be JSON or a form.

From the [Play Documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWS):

If you're sending a form:

```
request.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post("key1=value1&key2=value2") ...
```

Or posting JSON as a `String`:

```
request.setContentType("application/json").post(jsonString) ...
```

If you're having other compile errors, please post them.